# Updating a select option using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form where when something is updated, I need to change the name of that item in a select input.  I'm using this to loop through the options, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to change the text value.  Here is what I tried

```
$('#GroupID option').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == currently_editing_group_id)
                        $(this).attr('text', $('#NewGroupName').val());
                });
```

Here is the select input

```
<select id="PracticeGroupID" name="GroupID">
      <option value="5">Test Group 1</option>
      <option value="6">Test Group 2</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the base DOM properties `.text` and `.value` of the [`<option>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/option), like this:

```
$('#PracticeGroupID option').each(function () {
  if (this.value == currently_editing_group_id)
    this.text = $('#NewGroupName').val();
});
```

Or in the selector:

```
$("#PracticeGroupID option[value='"+currently_editing_group_id+"']").each(function () {
  this.text = $('#NewGroupName').val();
});
```

Note that you want `#PracticeGroupID` for your selector, since `#` is for the `id` and not the `name`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform and action when the value of the select **changes**, you should bind your function to the `change` even like this:

**HTML**

```
<select id="PracticeGroupID" name="GroupID">
    <option value="5">Test Group 1</option>
    <option value="6">Test Group 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="updateMe" value="" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#PracticeGroupID').change(function() {
    $('#updateMe').val('PracticeGroupID is ' + $(this).val());    
}).change();
```

You can try ti live here: http://jsfiddle.net/bTYWe/